# I get define DIR_UPLOAD error in opencart admin

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have my opencart webshop updated to the latest version. I now get the following error only on the admin page:

> define('DIR_UPLOAD',
>   '/home/barbecue/domains/barbecues-online.be/public_html/newbbq/system/upload/');
>   // OC 2 define('DIR_MODIFICATION',
>   '/home/barbecue/domains/barbecues-online.be/public_html/newbbq/system/modification/');
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/barbecue/domains/barbecues-online.be/public_html/newbbq/admin/config.php:4)
>   in
>   /home/barbecue/domains/barbecues-online.be/public_html/newbbq/admin/index.php
>   on line 12

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the config.php and admin/config.php. You will need to edit the following lines of code (9-18) in our example, located under // DIR:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/system usernamepublic_html/oc1551/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/system username/public_html/oc1551/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/stoychev/system username/oc1551/system/logs/');
```

Note: Please put your site Cpanel username under system username

then, You need to edit the Database entries lines (21-26)

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'stoychev_test');
define('DB_PASSWORD', ‘123456789);
define('DB_DATABASE', 'stoychev_oc1551');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Please fill in your USERNAME, PASSWORD and DATABASE under the ‘DB_USERNAME’, 'DB_PASSWORD' and “DB_DATABASE’

Please read this article for more informatino. http://isenselabs.com/posts/step-by-step-opencart-migration-to-a-new-server

Comment: Thanks!

Now I have only the following error on the admin page: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/barbecue/domains/barbecues-online.be/public_html/newbbq/admin/config.php:38) in /home/barbecue/domains/barbecues-online.be/public_html/newbbq/system/library/session.php on line 17

Comment: Please read this tutorial & follow Points no 4. Headers Already Sent - http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/common-opencart-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/